# Step by step with django-jet-demo

Tags: python, django, django-jet

I am trying to see django-jet-demo in action, i.e. https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet-demo, but It didn't work.

- `git clone https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet-demo.git`
- `mkvirtualenv venv`
- `cd django-jet-demo`
- `pip install -r requirements/base.txt`
- `django makemigrations`

I have the errors

1- `configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'common'`

If I remove `config.get(..., 'common')` inside `application/settings.py`

2- `configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'email'`

If I remove `config.get(..., 'email')` inside `application/settings.py`

3- `configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'database'`

How could I fix this problem? What are the steps to make django-jet-demo works? Does it work well on your computer?

### UPDATE

If I modify `default.conf` file, I got the same first error.

```
[common]
secret_key='t_g&c7^(!jb*$caaeue%$t_0pdtx5z(a7v%b6#svl1&0$5h9o-'
debug=False

[email]
server_email=test@test.com
host=localhost
port=1025
user=
password=
tls=True

[database]
ENGINE=django.db.backends.mysql
NAME=capitaine
USER=root
PASSWORD=wd9598%%DD
HOST='localhost'
PORT=3306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file named [`default.conf`](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet-demo/blob/master/default.conf) where the values of each section are empty and you should add appropriate values for at least `secret_key`, `server_email` and the `[database]` section.

If you don't want to use `mysql` as the db backend, use `sqlite` instead (without the need of `NAME`, `USER`, `PASSWORD` etc).

Also note that you have to create this `.conf` file under the path:

```
/path/to/project/conf/project_name.conf
```

Of course, change `project_name` to your actual project's name.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that file. Although I fill that file, I still have the same errors. I will modify the question. Did you test out `django-jet-demo`?

Comment: With `default.conf` inside the question, I still have the same first error, i.e. `configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'common'`

Comment: Hmmm... If you insert `print config_path` under `config_path=...` inside the settings file, what do you get? Also try removing the single quotes from each value (i.e use `NAME=capitaine` instead of `NAME='capitaine'`).

Comment: I got `/home/infinity/Projects/Work_Projects/django-jet-demo/conf/jet_demo.conf`.

Comment: OK, so does this file `j‌​et_demo.conf` exists under this path?

Comment: Weird, because there is no file jet_demo.conf.

Comment: That's what you have to create then. This file under this path. Got it?

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done. Thanks! Did you get the same problem?

Comment: Great. I've updated my answer to reflect your changes. Let me know if it worked.